# Some contacts not displayed when searching for them

Tags: iphone, contacts, ios

I have an iPhone 6 with the newest iOS.
Today a friend sent me a text message. After a few hours I went into
my contacts and tried searching for him but nothing came up even though I have him in contacts (checked by going into the message and clicking view contact).

This has actually happened several times before, searching for some contacts doesn't yield any result or shows something different even though that contact exists.

Anyone had the experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if you're using iCloud and it gets out of sync.  Go into `Settings --> iCloud` and turn off `Contacts`.  It will ask if you want to delete the contacts on your iPhone or keep them.  Choose to delete them from your iPhone.

Exit `iCloud` then go back into it.  Turn `Contacts` back on and allow it to sync your contacts back to your iPhone.  If everything worked ok, you should be able to find that person in your contacts again.

Comment: Does iCloud get outdated or my phone? Since if I delete the contacts from iPhone (assuming I have more there than on iCloud), I will lose some?

Comment: It depends on when you did the last update, assuming you have iCloud backups turned on and that you have Contacts backed-up.  Sometimes, after an iOS update usually, some backup settings are changed to 'off'.  Check you iCloud backup on your iPhone and see when the last one was done.  If it's recent, do what @christianboyce suggested, below, and check what's on the web.

Comment: It seems that my phone contacts are newer than the ones on the icloud. What to do now?

Comment: Do an iCloud backup and ensure you're backing up your contacts.  Once that's done, go online and verify they're all there.  At that point you can do the reset.

Comment: I selected on my iPhone to backup to icloud now and after it everything fixed itself, didn't even have to delete contacts.

Comment: That's great!  Please mark my answer as correct for people who are searching for a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iCloud it's good to go to www.icloud.com, sign in with your Apple ID and password, click the Contacts app on that web page, and see if the info there is better than on your iPhone. If it is, you can go ahead with the "turn off contacts on your iPhone, turn them back on" method. What you see at www.icloud.com is what Apple will sync to your device if you turn off contacts and then turn them back on so you want to be sure iCloud.com shows all of the contacts you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is simple, but I missed it before fooling around with iCloud. In contacts, tap on groups, and be sure to check all groups. One of my email accounts was listed as a group, and had not been checked.